# How to start a paragraph after an image?

Tags: html, image, wordpress

I am trying to make my wordpress HTML laid out as follows:

```
IMG paragraph 1 paragraph 1 
IMG paragraph 1 ..
IMG
IMG

paragraph 2...
```

where all the IMG refer to a single image and the second paragraph starts below the image. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, float your image left, and set paragraph 2 to clear.  In your CSS:

```
.left_img {
    float: left;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Set the class on your image to `left_img`, and on your paragraph, `clear`.  Obviously, choose class names that fit with what you are trying to do... this is just an example.

Comment: @epsalon, The one that you want to clear both left and right floats.  In your case, the second paragraph.  See also:  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html